# Using regular expressions to change "double" decimal constants in C to "float" constants

Tags: regex

I would like to change all numeric constants of the form XX.XXX to XX.XXXf avoiding constants already in the form XX.XXXf, where XX represents decimal numbers.
For example 10.04 would be changed to 10.04f and 5.08f would be unchanged.
The idea is to search for `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)([^f])` and replace with `\1f\2`

But... it doesn't really work... and I don't understand why. The first pattern `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` works, but if I add the second pattern `([^f])` 10.005f still matches.
On the other hand, if I modify the first pattern to test only one digit after the dot `([0-9]+\.[0-9])([^f])`, it works fine, but I would like it to work with several digits after the dot as well.

In fact, I understand that the last digit is seen as a character different from "f", and that's why it (10.005f) matches.

How to make it work regardless of the number of digits?

Thank you

Comment: You excluded the "f" from your negated character class, exclude the digits too.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+\b(?!f)', r'\g<0>f', text)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Zb2kCJ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    f                        'f'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Hello, Why did you change your answer?
In your first answer a \b was added... and it worked very well on notepad+ (and more or less well on the Segger IDE).
The new string (\d+\.\d+(?!f)) still works on notepad+ but less well on the Segger IDE. The string that works best on both platforms is (\b\d+\.\d+\b(?!f)), so why remove \b?

Comment: @user2897496 Can't please everyone here. Choose any solution, both work.

Comment: @user2897496 - Blame it on me. It was my recommendation `\d+\.\d+(?![\df])` since a word boundary `\b` never exists between a digit and `f` since both are a word. You can use `\d+\.\d+\b` but it will never match any word following it. See `You excluded the "f" from your negated character class, exclude the digits too` from the comments above, it's just a fact. Is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @user2897496 - Also in this `(?![\df])` it prevents it from matching `dd.dd`d to satisfy the regex. These are important boundary lessons that should be observed . Allows unrestricted anything else except the shorted digit and `f` and that's all you can do. Anything else is too restrictive. If you design restrictions then this is the minimum. Increase from here.